# A bash function to check if IP address is in two different files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a scenario here, I'm reading IP addresses every 10 seconds from a log file. How to check if that extracted IP is in another text file? 
I know grep has something to do with this, but how exactly?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
if grep -qw "$ipAddress" otherFile.txt; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Does that if function check if IP address is in two files?

Comment: the other file contain a list of unique IP addresses nothing else, I made it like a blacklist.

Comment: You should wrap `$ipAddress` with word boundary or beginning/ending line meta-characters so you don't get false positives on partial matches. (e.g., 1.2.3.4 is a substring of 1.2.3.40 and 11.2.3.4)